# I am not sure which download I require for VSCodium

Tags: software-installation, downloads

I've been using Ubuntu for about a week so total noob here.

I want to install VSCodium on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.

At the following, I do not know which download is most suitable:

https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/releases

Please could someone advise me?

If I had to guess, I would say - VSCodium-linux-x64-1.46.1.tar.gz

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following guide which worked seamlessly for me on Ubuntu 20.04:

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-vscodium-ide-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package ending with `amd64.deb` and run `sudo dpkg -i codium*amd64.deb`

You can also install `vscodium` as a `snap` package, this way you will get automatic updates

```
sudo apt-get install snap
sudo snap install codium
```